# Is it possible to save Dynamic Tables in SQL server?

Tags: java, sql, dynamic-tables

I'm working on a school project where I need to make a dynamic table in JavaFX, which should be saved in my SQL database.
The user should be able to specify the number of rows and columns needed.

Is it possible to save a dynamic table in SQL?

I've thought about exporting the dynamic table to a CSV file, and then save the information in the CSV file as a string. Then when you load the table again, a method would be needed to convert from string to table again. Seems like a stupid and inefficient way to do it though.

I've read some places that I should use XML or JSON in some way, but I never understood how.

Comment: Hi Casper. One usually creates a table, and saves data. What exactly do you mean? Creating tables, saving data, or both in one go? Your question is rather unclear on that.

Comment: @CasperJacobsen . . . Creating a separate table for each user is generally a bad approach to designing an application.

Comment: The system is a record keeping system. In one of the records, there needs to be a table, in which you can add as many Rows and Columns as you would like/need. This is for all the measurements/results you get from a Chemistry Experiment.
What I need is a way to save that table, in my SQL database

Comment: SQL databases are not meant for storing tables in rows. What you can do is keep detail records in a table, referencing the row in the other table by the primary key of that row.

Comment: If you need generic data, maybe a NoSQL-(document-based) Database is a better fit for your needs.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management as my Local Database by the way. But all in all, it's not really possible to save such a dynamic table in a SQL database? I'm not really that far in my education progress, so all I've been taught in are Java and SQL databases. What would you recommend to do/use as a solution to this problem?